Memory consumption increasing with camera loop
I have a python script for taking images and uploading them to my server.  This is a dumbed down version of it but reproduces the same result.  It captures and image but every loop it increases memory consumption until it eventually kills the script.  I'm using an RPi 4B with a 13mp USB camera.
import cv2, psutil, os, gc, time

def takepic():

    frame = None
    cw, ch = 4000, 3000
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    print('click!')
    cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, cw)
    cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, ch)
    time.sleep(0.6)
    suc, frame = cap.read()
    cap.release()

    process = psutil.Process(os.getpid())
    print(f'Memory Used {round(process.memory_percent(), 2)}%')
    resizeit(frame)

def resizeit(img):
    small = cv2.resize(img, (0,0), fx=0.5, fy=0.5)
    del small
    del img
    print(gc.get_count())
    gc.collect()
    print(gc.get_count())
    time.sleep(1)
    takepic()
    
takepic()

I've tired using del with the variables, setting to None and also the garbage collector to no avail.

Recursion is inappropriate here. Is it your intention to continually take "images" from your PC's camera? How would you stop the process?

This is just a dumbed down version of the code to reproduce the error.  I do have a trigger in my original code.  The memory still does not release with the trigger in place.

So what I've learned is that I can't release the array from memory after it's transferred to another function.  I've tried with both numpy and PIL array.  Anyone know why this is?

When you do del img it removes that reference to the image, but it's still referenced by the frame variable in the caller, so it won't be GCed. Use a loop so you don't have multiple references to the same object.

I just put a while True in there and it did the same thing.  Could you elaborate on how and where I would write that loop?
